# Can't redirect cut output

Tags: bash, io-redirection, cut, netcat

When I try to redirect the output of `cut` it always seems to be empty. If don't redirect it, the output shows in terminal as expected. This is true for OS X 10.10 and Linux 4.1.6.

This works:

```
root@karla:~# nc 10.0.2.56 30003
[...] lots of lines [...]
```

This works:

```
root@karla:~# nc 10.0.2.56 30003 | cat
[...] lots of lines [...]
```

This works:

```
root@karla:~# nc 10.0.2.56 30003 | cut -d, -f 15,16
[...] lots of lines [...]
```

This doesn't

```
root@karla:~# nc 10.0.2.56 30003 | cut -d, -f 15,16 | cat
[nothing]
```

This again *DOES*

```
root@karla:~# cat messung1 | cut -d, -f15,16 | cat
[...] lots of lines [...]
```

This is not limited to `cat` after `cut`. `grep`, `tee` and standard redirection using `>` don't work either.

What's wrong there?

Comment: Sounds like buffering issue, run `cut` with `stdbuf -oL cut...`

Comment: Hey, I just learned about new `coreutils` command.  Thanks, Stéphane!

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks, this fixes it for Linux. On OSX the problem persists.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas unfortunately, this didn't improve over `cut`

Comment: To find the reason for this problem, I recommend to run cut under truss(1) or your local equivalent. Use `truss -o o cut ... `and later check the content for the file o.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not that much that there's no output as that it's coming in chunks.

Like many programs, when its output is no longer a terminal, `cut` buffers its output. That is, it only writes data when it has accumulated a buffer-full of it. Typically, something like 4 or 8 KiB though YMMV.

You can easily verify it by comparing:

```
(echo foo; sleep 1; echo bar) | cut -c2-
```

With:

```
(echo foo; sleep 1; echo bar) | cut -c2- | cat
```

In the first case, `cut` outputs `oo\n` and then `ar\n` one second later, while in the second case, cut outputs `oo\nar\n` after 1 seconds, that is when it sees the end of its input and flushes its output upon exit.

In your case, since stdin is `nc`, it would only see the end of its input when the connection is closed, so it would only start outputting anything after it has accumulated 4KiB worth of data to write.

To work around that, several approaches are possible.

- On GNU or FreeBSD systems, you can use the `stdbuf` utility that can tweak the buffering behaviour of some commands (it doesn't work for all as it uses a LD_PRELOAD hack to pre-configure the stdio buffering behaviour).

  ```
  ... | stdbuf -oL cut -d, -f15,16 | cat
  ```

  would tell `cut` to do a line-based buffering on its stdout.
- some commands like GNU `grep` have options to affect their buffering. (`--line-buffered` in the case of GNU `grep`).
- you can use a pseudo-tty wrapper to force the stdout of a command to be a terminal. However most of those solutions have some drawbacks and limitations. The `unbuffer` `expect` script for instance, often mentioned to address this kind of problem has a number of bugs for instance.

  One that doesn't work too bad is when using `socat` as:

  ```
  ... | socat -u 'exec:"cut -d, -f15,16",pty,raw' -
  ```
- You can replace your text utility with a higher-level text processing tool that has support for unbuffered output.

  - GNU `awk` for instance has a `fflush()` function to flush its output. So your `cut -d, -f15,16` could be written:

    ```
    awk -F, -vOFS=, '{print $15,$16;fflush()}'
    ```
  - if your `awk` lacks the `fflush()` function, you can use `system("")` instead. That's normally the command to execute a command. Here, we would be executing an empty command, but actually using it for the fact that `awk` flushes its stdout before running the command.
  - or you can use `perl`:

    ```
    perl -F, -lane 'BEGIN{$,=",";$|=1} print @F[14..15]'
    ```

Comment: Thanks. On OSX the only thing I can do right now is to wait.

Comment: on OSX you make be able to `brew install coreutils` to get stdbuf