# How does a program know if stdout is connected to a terminal or a pipe?

Tags: terminal, pipe

I'm having trouble debugging a segfaulting program because the ouput right before the segfault is what I need, but this is lost if I'm piping the output to a file. According to this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/17339/22615, this is because the output buffer of the program flushes immediately when connected to a terminal but only at certain points when connected to a pipe. A few questions here:

- How does a program determine what its stdout is connected to?
- How does the "script" command produce the same behavior as when the program writes to a terminal?
- Can this be achieved without the script command?

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/513926/5132 .

Answer (score 46, accepted):

### Telling if a file descriptor points to a terminal device

A program can tell if a file descriptor is associated with a tty device by using the [`isatty()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/isatty.html) standard C function (which generally underneath does an innocuous tty-specific `ioctl()` system call that would return with an error when the fd doesn't point to a tty device).

The `[`/`test` utility can do it with its `-t` operator.

```
if [ -t 1 ]; then
  echo stdout is open to a terminal
fi
```

Tracing libc function calls on a GNU/Linux system:

```
$ ltrace [ -t 1 ] | cat
[...]
isatty(1)                                      = 0
[...]
```

Tracing system calls:

```
$ strace [ -t 1 ] | cat
[...]
ioctl(1, TCGETS, 0x7fffd9fb3010)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
[...]
```

### Telling if it points to a pipe

To determine whether a fd is associated with a pipe/fifo, one can use the [`fstat()` system call](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/fstat.html), which returns a structure whose `st_mode` field contains the type and permissions of the file opened on that fd. The [`S_ISFIFO()` standard C macro](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html) can be used on that `st_mode` field to determine if the fd is a pipe/fifo.

There is no standard utility that can do a `fstat()`, but there are several incompatible implementations of a `stat` command that can do it. `zsh`'s `stat` builtin with `stat -sf "$fd" +mode` which returns the mode as a string representation whose first character represents the type (`p` for pipe). GNU `stat` can do the same with `stat -c %A - <&"$fd"`, but also has `stat -c %F - <&"$fd"` to report the *type* alone. With BSD `stat`: `stat -f %St <&"$fd"` or `stat -f %HT <&"$fd"`.

### Telling if it's seekable

Applications generally do not care if stdout is a pipe though. They may care that it's seekable (though generally not to decide whether to buffer or not).

To test whether a fd is seekable (pipes, sockets, tty devices are not seekable, regular files and most block devices generally are), one can attempt a relative [`lseek()` system call](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/lseek.html) with an offset of 0 (so innocuous). `dd` is a standard utility that's an interface to `lseek()` but it can't be used for that test, as implementations would not call `lseek()` at all if you ask for an offset of 0.

The `zsh` and `ksh93` shells have builtin seeking operators though:

```
$ strace -e lseek ksh -c ': 1>#((CUR))' | cat
lseek(1, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
ksh: 1: not seekable
$ strace -e lseek zsh -c 'zmodload zsh/system; sysseek -w current -u 1 0 || syserror'
lseek(1, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
Illegal seek
```

### Disabling the buffering

The `script` command uses a pseudo-terminal pair to capture the output of a program, so the program's stdout (and stdin and stderr) will be a pseudo-terminal device.

When the stdout is to a terminal device, there is still generally some buffering, but it is line based. `printf`/`puts` and co will not write anything until a newline character is to be output. For other types of files, the buffering is by blocks (of a few kilo bytes).

There are several options to disable the buffering which are discussed in a number of Q&As here (search for [unbuffer](/search?q=unbuffer) or [stdbuf](/search?q=stdbuf), [Can't redirect cut output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/226625) gives a few approaches) either by using a pseudo-terminal as can be done by `socat`/`script`/`expect`/`unbuffer` (an `expect` script)/`zsh`'s `zpty` or by injecting code in the executable to disable the buffering as done by GNU's or FreeBSD's `stdbuf`.

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you very much for this!

Comment: Another, Linux-specific approach is to traverse `/proc` directory and for each `/proc/<integer>/` directory look into `/proc/<integer>/fd/` and find file descriptor that has same inode number in `pipefs`  https://serverfault.com/q/48330/363611  However, that is only useful in scripts when one cannot use the syscalls described in Stephane's answer, and is more of a workaround than proper solution IMHO

Comment: On BSD, `lseek` will succeed on terminals and other character devices, and simply re/set a counter which is increased on each successful read(). I don't know whether this makes them "seekable".

Comment: @mowwwalker If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: This Perl bit works to tell if stdin is seekable: `$ date | perl -e 'binmode STDIN ; seek(STDIN,0,0) or exit 1' || echo Perl bad seek` gives output `Perl bad seek` because of the pipe, but is silent if you redirect stdin from a file.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting `-t`, I've read the help a million times but never registered that it exists ⭐️

Comment: This is a pretty brilliant answer.