# how can i detect user input is coming from pipe line or with parameters? (as using "if else")

Tags: shell-script, pipe, parameter

how can i detect user input is coming from pipe line or with parameters? (as using "if else")

**example:**

with pipeline

```
$ cat input_file | ./example.sh
hello
world
```

with parameters

```
$ ./example.sh "hello" "world"
hello
world
```

**my false code:**

I write url slug shell script. I have a one function for url parsing in script. I use that function for pipe `cat a | ./example.sh` or user input `./example.sh "hello" "world"`. My code is correct but I don't understand how detect and check user input is pipe or parameters.

sorry my english

```
#!/bin/bash

# define replacements
declare -a repls=(
    "Ğg"
    "ğg"
    "Çc"
    "çc"
    "Şs"
    "şs"
    "Üu"
    "üu"
    "Öo"
    "öo"
    "İi"
    "ıi"
    " -"
    "--"
)

function slug() {
    slug=""

    for (( i=0; i<${#arg}; i++ )) 
    do
        char="${arg:$i:1}"
        ascii=$(printf "%d" "'$char")

        # if alphanumeric
        # locale encoding should be UTF-8 for this values to work
        if [[ ( $ascii -ge 48 && $ascii -le 57 ) || # numbers
            ( $ascii -ge 65 && $ascii -le 90 ) ||  # uppercase
            ( $ascii -ge 97 && $ascii -le 122 ) ]]; then # lowercase
            slug="$slug$char"
        else
            for (( j=0; j < ${#repls[@]}; j++ ))
            do
                from=${repls[$j]:0:1}
                to=${repls[$j]:1:1}
                if [[ $char == $from ]]; then
                    slug="$slug$to"
                    break
                fi
            done
        fi
    done

    if [[ $slug == "" ]]; then
        echo "words should contain at least one valid character"
        exit 1
    fi

    echo $slug | awk '{print tolower($0)}'
}

#FOR PARAMETERS
for arg in "$@"
do
 slug;
done

##FOR READ PIPE
[[ -z "$@" ]] && while read arg;
do
 slug;    
done
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the question. User input is coming from STDIN (your pipe) if it goes through the loop, and from arguments otherwise. So, you are already using `[[ -z "$@" ]]` for this test.

Comment: Personally, I would make sure that the documentation makes it clear how the program _should_ be invoked (i.e. one way or the other). It's unclear what you want should happen in the case where there are both command line arguments _and_ input on standard input from a pipe.

Comment: @LjmDullaart Note that no specific shell was mentioned and that `[ -z "$@" ]` (in `sh`) would fail if there are multiple command line arguments. Better to use `[ "$#" -eq 0 ]`.

Comment: @Kusalananda I was merely doing the observation that he already used that test to, in the OP's own words "detect user input is coming from pipe line or with parameters" and, since he already used this test, I did not understand his issue.

Comment: I rewrote my code. please look this code and my quenstion?

Comment: not a typo. because the string is processed letter by letter.

Comment: @Kusalananda not exists for turkish langauge. (specifically written to encoding/decoding URLs). I write a html generator with bash. I dont use more addiction (python, java etc.)

Comment: @roaima no I dont used tr, must I try? my script also delete non-ascii chracters

Comment: Actually, I don't think `tr` will work in this situation. Sorry about the misleading there. I'm going to remove my earlier comment, and I'll remove this one shortly too.

Comment: I found how make this: `if tty -s
then
echo Terminal
else
echo Not on a terminal
fi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do:

```
something_with() {
  printf 'Processing "%s"\n' "$1"
}

ret=0
if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
  # process args on command line

  for arg do
    something_with "$arg" || ret=$?
  done
else
  # no arg, processing lines of stdin instead:

  while IFS= read -r "$arg" || [ -n "$arg" ]; do
    # redirect something_with's stdin to /dev/null to make sure
    # it doesn't interfere with the list of args.
    </dev/null something_with "$arg" || ret=$?
  done
fi

exit "$ret"
```

(note that it means the arguments sent via stdin cannot contain newline characters).

Though you could also only take input as arguments, but invoke your script as:

```
xargs -rd '\n' -a input_file your-script
```

(here assuming GNU `xargs`), for `xargs` to pass the contents of the lines in `input_file` as arguments to `your-script` (in that case `your-script` may be called several time by `xargs` to work around the limit on the maximum number of arguments to a command).

In any case, I'd say you don't want to check whether stdin is a pipe or not here.

1. First that `cat input_file | your-script` is a *Useless Use of Cat* (infamous UUoC). Generally, if you want to feed the contents of a file as input to command, you use `< input_file your-scrip` or `your-script < input_file`, in which case your script's stdin will not be a pipe (unless `input_file` itself is a named pipe).
2. Your script could be called with stdin connected with a pipe even though you don't want it to read it, like for instance in `ssh host your-script arg1 arg2` (where stdin a a pipe to `sshd`) or `... | while IFS= read -r foo; do your-script "x$foo"; done` or `cmd | xargs your-script` (with some `xargs` implementation; some redirect stdin to /dev/null instead there).

But if you really wanted to, that's already addressed in a separate question on this site: [How does a program know if stdout is connected to a terminal or a pipe?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/515778) with the different that here it's stdin instead of stdout, so file descriptor 0 instead of 1.

Comment: I rewrote my code. please look this code and my quenstion?

Comment: the code you suggested works correctly but I want pipe available

Comment: @rojen, that code will read stdin whether it's a pipe or not as long as you don't pass any argument to the script.

Comment: i will try the suggestion. thanks for helping, @Stephane.  and than I am coming

Comment: I found how make this: `if tty -s then echo Terminal else echo Not on a terminal fi`

Comment: @rojen, why would you want to read stdin when it's not a terminal. What about the `ssh host your-script args` case or the your script being called from cron or from a desktop file when there's no terminal.

Comment: because when the user input is "stdin" or "stdout", It should take working by deciding which of these is what, But now the problem is, what to do when the two are together?

Comment: @rojen and what should happen when there are some arguments but stdin is not a terminal device?

Comment: In any case, if you really wanted to detect whether stdin is a terminal or a pipe, that's already addressed in [How does a program know if stdout is connected to a terminal or a pipe?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/515778)

Comment: thanks i mean it this. however, what you said is a correct statement. so I will tick because it can help others

Answer (score -2):

You may check if your shell is interactive via the `$-` variable or via the `$PS1` variable:

```
case "$-" in
*i*)    echo This shell is interactive ;;
*)  echo This shell is not interactive ;;
esac
```

or

```
if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
        echo This shell is not interactive
else
        echo This shell is interactive
fi
```

The above examples are copied from [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Is-this-Shell-Interactive_003f.html).

Thanks to @Kusalananda:
one further option to check if parameters are piped into the script:

```
if [ -t 0 ]; then
  echo "This shell is interactive"
fi
```

Comment: Also, `[ -t 0 ]` will be true if standard input is open and connected to a terminal.

Comment: thank you for pointing this out - I will add this to the answer

Comment: How does looking at `$-` help? It doesn't contain `i` regardless of if the script was started with `./foo.sh asdf`, `echo asdf | ./foo.sh`, or `bash < ./foo.sh`. An interactive shell is where the shell commands are read from a terminal (roughly), but here they come from the script file. Sure, you could run `bash -i ./foo.sh`, but that's not really very user-friendly to require.